# localizing rings in SAGE

Tags: sage

I am a bit of SAGE newb, so I apologize if this is a simplistic question.

I want to use SAGE to compute some invariants of elliptic curves defined over rings which aren't the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ or the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$. More specifically, I am interested looking at elliptic curves defined over the ring 
$$
\mathbb{Z}[1/6][c_4,c_6]
$$
or 
$$
\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}[c_4,c_6]
$$
where $p$ is some prime. Can anyone tell me how produce a localized ring such as $\mathbb{Z}[1/6]$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ in SAGE? Or know where in the manual I could find such information?

Thanks!

Comment: You might have more luck on [Ask Sage](https://ask.sagemath.org/),
a dedicated questions and answers website for SageMath.